# Array is larger than allocated?

Tags: c

I have an array that's declared as char buff[8]. That should only be 8 bytes, but looking as the assembly and testing the code, I get a segmentation fault when I input something larger than 32 characters into that buff, whereas I would expect it to be for larger than 8 characters. Why is this?

Comment: Why wouldn't you expect some problem trying to stuff 32 characters into an array that has room for 8?  Consider yourself lucky it failed there so you can identify the problem.

Comment: That's undefined behavior - it hardly ever does what you expect. Once you go past your buffer of 8 chars, nothing might happen. Or it might crash, or it might crash at some completely unrelated point on code and time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you're saying is not a contradiction:

- You have space for 8 characters.
- You get an error when you input more than 32 characters.

So what?

The point is that nobody told you that you would be guaranteed to get an error if you input more than 8 characters. That's simply **undefined behaviour**, and anything can (and will) happen.

You absolutely mustn't think that the absence of obvious misbehaviour is *proof* of the correctness of your code. Code correctness can only be verified by checking the code against the rules of the language (though some automated tools such as `valgrind` are an immense help).

Comment: I should add that another way of thinking about programming is that the number of ways in which the programmer can mess up exceeds by far the number of errors that a program can produce.

Answer (score 6):

Writing beyond the end of the array is undefined behavior. Undefined behavior means **nothing** (including a segmentation fault) **is guaranteed**.

In other words, it might do anything. More practical, it's likely the write didn't touch anything protected, so *from the point of view of the OS* everything is still OK until 32.

This raises an interesting point. What is "totally wrong" from the point of view of C might be OK with the OS. The OS only cares about what pages you access:

- Is the address mapped for your process ?
- Does your process have the rights ?

You shouldn't count on the OS slapping you if anything goes wrong. A useful tool for this (slapping) is valgrind, if you are using Unix. It will warn you if your process is doing nasty things, even if those nasty things are technically OK with the OS.

Answer (score 2):

Your declaration `char buff[8]` sounds like a stack allocated variable, although it could be heap allocated if part of a struct. Accessing out of bounds of an array is undefined behaviour and is known as a buffer overrun. Buffer overruns on stack allocated memory may corrupt the current stack frame and possibly other stack frames in the call stack. With undefined behaviour, anything could happen, including no apparent error. You would not expect a seg fault immediately because the stack is typically when the thread starts.

For heap allocated memory, memory managers typically allocate large blocks of memory and then sub-allocate from those larger blocks. That is why you often don't get a seg fault when you access beyond the end of a block of memory.

It is undefined behaviour to access beyond the end of a memory block. And it is perfectly valid, according to the standard, for such out of bounds accesses to result in seg faults or indeed an apparently successful read or write. I say *apparently* successful because if you are writing then you will quite possibly produce a heap corruption by writing out of bounds.

Answer (score 2):

C arrays have no bound checking.

As other said, you are hitting undefined behavior; until you stay inside the bounds of the array, everything works fine. If you cheat, as far as the standard is concerned, anything can happen, including your program seeming to work right as well as the explosion of the Sun.

What happens in practice is that with stack-allocated variables you are likely to overwrite other variables on the stack, getting "impossible" bugs, or, if you hit a canary value put by the compiler, it may detect the buffer overflow on return from the function. For variables allocated in the so-called heap, the heap allocator may have given some more room than requested, so the mistake may be less easy to spot, although you may easily mess up the internal structures of the heap.

In both cases you can also hit a protected memory page, which will result in your program being terminated forcibly (for the stack this happens less often because usually you have to overwrite the entire stack to get to a protected page).

Answer (score -1):

Unless you are not telling us something you answered your owflown question.

declaring

```
char buff[8] ;
```

means that the compiler grabs 8 bytes of memory.  If you try and stuff 32 **char**'s into it you should get a seg fault, that's called a buffer overflow.

Each char is a byte ( unless you are doing unicode in which it is a word ) so you are trying to put 4x the number of chars that will fit in your buffer.

Is this your first time coding in C ?

Comment: "Is this your first time coding in C?" is really not appropriate here.

Comment: The question is why the segmentation fault doesn't occur immediately after writing past the end of the buffer, not why it eventually overflows after writing 32.

Comment: David, the question was not pejorative.  First time coder often need more of an explanation.  In my world there is no such thing as a stupid question, well perhaps except for the one you didn't ask.