# Dynamic array confusion

Tags: c, malloc, dynamic-arrays

I was just brushing up my C concepts a bit where I got confused about some behavior. Consider the following code snippet:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main (){


    int * arr;
    arr= malloc(3*sizeof(*arr));
    arr[0]=1;
    arr[1]=2;
    arr[2]=3;
    arr[3]=4;
    printf("value is %d \n", arr[3]);

return 0;


}
```

The problem is that the program functions correctly! As far as I understand I allocate memory for an array of 3 integers. So basically when I try to put a value in `arr[3]`  there should be a `segmentation fault` as no memory has been assigned for it.  But it works fine and prints the value 4.
Either this is some weird behavior or I seriously need to revise basic C. Please if anyone can offer some explanation I would highly appreciate it.
Thanks.

Comment: already seen so many times: possible duplicate of [Array is larger than allocated?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8057584/array-is-larger-than-allocated)

Comment: I agree.  This or similar question seems to be posted every few days.

Answer (score 10):

Technically, It is **Undefined Behavior**, Which means anything can happen not necessarily a segmentation fault.
Just your program is not a valid program and you should not write invalid programs and expect valid /invalid behaviors from them.

Answer (score 6):

You could get a segmentation fault at any time, you got "lucky" this time. This is **undefined** behavior, so you might get a seg fault some other time.

C does **not** do any bounds checking, so while e.g., Java would have complained, C is quite happy to do whatever you ask it to do, even to the program's own detriment.

This is both one of its major strengths, and also weaknesses.

Answer (score 3):

Your program has [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). This does not mean that it is guaranteed to segfault. The failure might manifest itself in other ways (or not at all).

Answer (score 2):

Here's my guess based on my understanding of how memory is allocated (it may be wrong - so vote it down if it is!):

The address of `arr[3]` is in a memory page that your app has permission to write to. I think 4KB is a common page size. The `malloc` call resulted in 1 page being mapped to your app, of which you're only using the first `3*sizeof(*arr)` bytes, therefore there is space left after `arr[2]` which your app has permission to write to, but `malloc` has yet to issue. If you were to perform another `malloc` the returned address will be bigger than `arr` and may equal the address of `arr[3]`.